# Does Nodejs Kafkajs producer have internal buffer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, producer, kafkajs

[This](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/1161) may imply [Kafkajs producer](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs) doesn't have internal buffer. What would be the best practices to handle heavy traffic(e.g 1k number of messages or 100Mb size per second ) sent out by producer? For example, assume the upper limit (e.g. max num of msg or size of total msg) of a producer can handle is N. When traffic is 2N, how does Kafkajs producer handle it? Does anyone have experience in production to share?

Comment: Commented on gjthub issue

Comment: just read the code, the encoder does have internal buffer, https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/blob/1876abcb5effd6183c1fbaa50dee9cef269b67a5/src/protocol/encoder.js#L67 but it is configurable at this point. What is the best way to handle when buffer is full

Comment: The `ensureAvailable` function there seems to handle that case